# Keep Spaces in Rd Files

Tags: r, format, rd

I'd like to retain multiple spaces in the \details{} section's text of an Rd help file, which by default are compressed to one single space.
The result should look like:

[image]

Either this is super trivial or impossible. Any ideas out there?

Comment: Yes, I do it usually by hand, but would be willing to change, if there's a solution for this in roxygen...

Comment: A lot of Rd info here: https://colinfay.me/writing-r-extensions/writing-r-documentation-files.html Maybe try the `\sspace` macro.

Comment: I did, doesn't work... :-( 
I also tried \phantom{}, \preformatted{}, all kinds of \eqn{}, but no success

Comment: I have a solution \verb{   } or in roxygen2 `  `, where add many spaces

Comment: Hey! This is great! This seems to work. Enter it as answer to get your points.

Comment: I just added it. I am glad that could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add \verb{           } or in roxygen2 `              `, with proper numer of spaces .

Comment: Yes! Works perfectly in the HTML and PDF view. Thanks a lot.
Where did you get your information from?

Comment: I tested a few ideas add hoc. Normally i know about \text{} trick e.g. in Latex/Math so tried to look for sth similar.